# Nice ways to collect pyplot graphs into a single page/document/etc?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter

I'm currently working on a program that plots many graphs. I'm using Jupyter. It works okay so far, but it is printing each graph to its own window. This is less than ideal because there are hundreds of graphs.

What are some ways to condense the output? I am hoping for a way to have the many graphs sent to a single document/window.

Also, I am iterating over a dictionary and only plotting graphs when the program encounters something of interest, so the frequency is not very predictable. It is something like this:

```
while still_true:
    if my_condition is True:
        a = np.arange(20) // not actually a range, but a dynamic np array
        plt.plot(a)
        plt.ylabel("some numbers")
        plt.show()
```

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for [subplots](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html)

Comment: Since you mentioned *a single document*, I'd mention the *pdf_pages* backend.

Comment: @ali_m It sounds like you might be right! Is there a concise way to plot the rows of an mxn matrix as subplots sharing the same x-axis (each row to its own plot)?

Comment: Sure, I like to use [`fig, ax = plt.subplots(..., sharex=True)`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=subplots#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots) to generate new figure with a grid of subplots that share a common x-axis. `ax` is a numpy array of axis objects, so you can use `ax[0].plot(...); ax[1].plot(...)` etc.

Comment: @ali_m Where the `...` in `plt.subplots(..., sharex=True)` = m?

Comment: @ali_m It seems to have worked, but it has made the image extremely condensed. I was hoping that it would keep graphs dimensions and increase the dimension of the image, rather than shrinking the graphs to fit into the image dimension. Any suggestions?

Comment: You could set the size of the figure by passing the `figsize=(w, h)` argument to `plt.subplots`, where `w` and `h` are the width and height of the image in inches (I'm not quite sure how this argument interacts with Jupyter). It can also be helpful to call [`fig.tight_layout()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/tight_layout_api.html) which attempts to automatically adjust the subplots in order to fit them nicely into the figure. Obviously there is a limit as to how much data will comfortably fit into a single image.

Comment: @ali_m So I passed `figsize=(10,1000)` to `plt.subplots(...)` and it didn't seem to do anything. The image appeared to be the same size in the output window, and there was no ability to scroll. Any other suggestions besides outputting n plots per call to `plt.show()`?

Comment: The `figsize` argument seems to work for me, at least with reasonable width/height arguments  (I'm actually surprised that it didn't throw some sort of error when you asked it for a 25 metre tall figure...)